# Is it practical to run a WordPress site at EC2 using Route 53, without an elastic IP?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm running five wordpress sites (@EC2) all having it's own elastic IP tied to a proper domain name. I reached the max limit when wanted to launch another site (another domain).

Besides of the obvious; asking for more EIPs, can I use route 53 and pointing to the dynamic EC2 hostname?

As far as I understand this will destroy/mess-up all internal links of the wordpress instance, the moment I reboot or stop/start the instance, because it gets a new IP/hostname and all image-links of wordpress by default are absolute for SEO reasons.

Has anybody found a solution to this, or is my only option to ask for more EIPs?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, requesting more EIP's is going to be the easier way to go.

You can set up your DNS to point the public ip of any instance, if its not an eip, it will change if the instance ever stop/started again. In which case you need to update DNS.

Wordpress doesn't really care what the hostname or ip address is of the instance. It cares what hostname you want it to respond to. Even if the underlying ip changes, as long as the hostname records are updated to the new IP, you wont have any issues.